# How to design user id for a website?

Tags: python, html, django, algorithm, web

I am working on a toy website and I have implemented an upvote button, with an onclick attribute like this:

```
Dajaxice.debater.upvote(
    upvote_js,//Don't worry about this, it's just dealing with AJAX
    {
         'username' : 'bob',//bob is the user being upvoted by
    }
)
```

You see the problem is the webpage is using the username directly, it is bad design since the user can easily open a chrome console, change the usernames and fake a request that upvote say alice instead of bob. I have investigated a couple of websites and see they are using a long string looks like hash to represent users. I am wondering how is this implemented usually? In more general form, I am looking for an algorithm that:

1. Gives an unique id for every user
2. Even if this id is given exposed to user or any third party, they will have no idea which user this id represents without using a long time or a lot of memory to compute(reverse the hash).

Comment: How is the server implemented? Are you using a framework?

Comment: @Aya I am using django

Comment: Are you using Django's [built-in authentication framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/)?

Comment: @Aya Yes I used. But here bob is not the request.user, bob is the one being upvoted, the upvoter may be someone like mike.

Comment: What's the use-case here? Is the idea you're upvoting users, or some message the user has posted?

Comment: @Aya yeah its someone upvoting some other guy, like mike upvote bob, not upvoting the post, just upvote another user.

Comment: Basically you could use some salt, username and date of account creation to generate a SHA-2 hash. Or you could generate haszhes for one-time use, which would be even safer. Anyway, if logged in user can upvote any other user, then there is no point in obscuring username, as mike can upvote both bob and alice anyway.

Comment: @KrzysztofBujniewicz Umm... That's true but I just dont like the idea that someone can fake a request to my site.

Comment: If you really want users to be unable to fake vote requests, generate unique hash for a pair voter/voted, although that is probably an overkill. Keeping any form of permanent ids in code would be prone to scraping them and sending fake requests anyway. Although, as I said, in this case it is not a threat to the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate an encrypted form of the string (a hash, by definition, is not reversible).

The drawback to this is if someone has a list of all your users, they can then calculate the algorithm you used and defeat your encryption.

A common way to do *reversible* encryption is with [`base64`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html):

```
>>> import base64
>>> secret = base64.b64encode('bob')
>>> secret
'Ym9i'
>>> print base64.b64decode('Ym9i')
bob
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like this is a design issue, rather than a coding problem.

Even if you hashed the usernames somehow, there would always be a way to get the hash by finding an instance of that hash on a webpage somewhere.

You could implement a system such that each user may only upvote another user once, but there's nothing to stop someone from creating multiple accounts to bypass the limitation.

One common solution is to keep track of which IP addresses have upvoted a particular user, and disallow multiple upvotes for the same user from the same IP address.